# Double integrals over general regions (Why the formulas are as they are)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

So i am currently learning about double integrals and to be honest i am not really understanding how we compute the volume over general regions. Here is the proof provided in my text book.[image]

[image]

It all makes sense until the last part. Since we use Fubini's theorem we can change the order in which we integrate. Since that is true wouldn't that mean that the Fubinis Theorem applies to all double integrals? Since this is obviously not true can you point out what am i doing wrong? IF you need any more clarification/photos please comment.

Comment: I guess this is Stewart? In any case it might be a good idea to cite the text.

Comment: Yup, this is stewart. "Multivariable Calculus"

Comment: Fubinis theorem applies to any bounded box in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In general it works for any finite measure space

Comment: @Chanler Exactly, and here they make a general region a box but at places where we do not want the volume we say f(x,y)=0. So technicaly it is a box and we can use fubinis theorem.

Comment: What have you done that you wan't us to point out what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @skyking well what i am saying is the order of integration can be changed even if we are dealing with Type 1 and 2 plane regions.

Comment: The important point is that the region is on a bounded subset. In this case these is no problem with integral order. It is only when dealling with unbounded functions that things get messy.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a conceptual issue with what Fubini's Theorem implies (as it is formulated by Stewart). His formulation goes like this: If $f$ is bounded on some rectangle $R$, is discontinuous at most on finitely many smooth curves and the iterated integrals exist, we have

$$\int_R f dA = \int_x \int_y f dy dx = \int_y \int_x f dx dy,$$

where in the iterated integrals one takes integral in one direction, each of which giving an expression (possibly) dependent on the other variable, and then takes the integral of this newly obtained expression in the other direction.

Now the second equality indeed means that no matter which order one takes the iterated integrals the result will be the same. The first equality on the other hand tells something more primordial: it provides an effective method to actuate a integral over a region, namely it converts this more complicated integral to integrals over intervals, which were described before (in the textbook), provided $f$ behaves nicely on the domain of integration. In other words Fubini's Theorem allows us to regard $dA$ as $dx dy$ or $dy dx$ under certain conditions. Note that in the page you have provided the conversion of $dA$ to $dy dx$ is used.

Given that the hypotheses of Fubini are satisfied, you are correct to say that one can change the order of integration, even when the domain of integration is determined by functions $g_i$. However, when you do change the order you have to attend to the functions $g_i$ also, as they are likely to be not functions when considered in the other direction. So you may need to find new functions $h_i$ that depend on the other variable and that still give the boundary of the region on which $f$ is to be integrated. To accomplish this you might need to divide the region of integration into smaller parts.

---

As an exercise you may want to consider the following: Let $f$ be a function that Fubini is keen on, and take $R$ to be that region which is bounded by the $x$-axis and $g(x):=1-x^2$. Then write down the integral of $f$ in all forms provided by Fubini with explicit bounds.

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this you can change the order. However the important thing to note is that if you change the order there will be times when you need to change the limits of integration. In the example the area of integration is a rectangle so x and y are not related for rewriting the area integral as two iterated integrals. For more complex areas the limits of your inner integral will be a function of the outer integral.

Comment: I am talking about the limits being functions as well. The book proves why the formula is as it is for a general region. It looks to me like the order of integration can be changed even if the limits are function.

Comment: Yes, but this "function" must be  bounded so that the volume of the area you integrate over is finite.

Comment: The functions of the limits will change when you change the order.

Comment: Exactly, why is that. Going by the definition from the book we can apply gubinis theorem to it?

Comment: Writing the boundaries in the form $f(x)$ or $g(y)$ will be inherently different. Imagine an integral on the area bound by $y=x^2$ and $y=4$. You could write $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{x^2}^4F(x,y)dydx$$ or $$\int_0^4\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}F(x,y)dxdy$$

Comment: @IanMiller how did you come up with these new boundries? I cannot seem to make sense of them